# Understanding React-Admin translation

Tags: react-admin, language-translation

I am working with `react-admin` and trying to traduce it to my native language with this short guide usage:
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-language-french

I keep getting non-referenced keys on the supposed translated keys.

To get my traduction working, I tried to delete node-modules file, tested in other browsers, cleared cache etc. but I still had the non-referenced keys: *ra.______*

When I changed this line (as below), it solved my problem:

```js
const messages = { 'fr': frenchMessages, };
```

TO

```js
const messages = { 'en': frenchMessages, };
```

And that's the only thing that i needed to change for the polyglot to work (French traduction).
Can someone explain to me what's going on, i don't know why it works in that case ?

**Example in picture which shows the case explained above:**

[Not working case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WIXU.png)

[Working case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZ54G.png)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This seems broken, I agree, and I don't know the correct solution right away. But what happens, if you make your `polyglotI18nProvider` non-dynamic, like shown here https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/docs/Translation.md#changing-the-default-locale? You'd just hard-code it like this: `polyglotI18nProvider(() => frenchMessages, 'fr');`. Let me know what happens if you try that approach.

Comment: It would greatly be helpful if you kindly mentioned which version of `react-admin` you are using. Thanks

Comment: Sure,   "version": "3.2.3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<Admin locale='fr' ...` property is deprecated! New version:

```
import { resolveBrowserLocale } from 'react-admin'
...
const i18nProvider = polyglotI18nProvider(locale => messages[locale], resolveBrowserLocale()) // or 'fr'
```

Comment: So, that means @DiSiZ issue is actually that their browser language is `en`? Then, if they want to only support `fr`, my solution from above will also fix that problem ;-)